# How to create and manage multiple identical PostgreSQL schemas with Prisma, apply migrations programmatically, and dynamically connect to schemas?

Tags: postgresql, prisma

I'm working with Prisma and PostgreSQL and I'm trying to build an application that requires multiple identical schemas in the database. Each user of the application should have their schema in the database.

How can I create and manage multiple PostgreSQL schemas with Prisma? I want to be able to create new schema "on the fly".

How can I use migrations with Prisma so that changes to the database are applied to all created schemas? I want to avoid the need to make migrations for each schema separately since they are identical.

Please provide a JS example of how to dynamically connect to different schemas with prisma.

Comment: How many users do you have? Are you going to run a prisma migration to create a schema whenever someone signs up?

Comment: I still don't have users. I guess I will have to run a migration for every new user.

Comment: Ok then how many users do you expect? ten, thousands, millions?

Comment: Well, I would say several thousands at most

Comment: Then don't. I would be really inefficient to have thousands of copies of nearly empty tables. Create a single table and store the the data for all the users in it, by adding the user id as an extra column (and making it part of any unique/primary key). Do that with all tables in your schema.